Upgrading 22.04 Python to 3.10.12 fails to fully install
I have upgraded python to 3.10.12 from the Ubuntu repositories on a computer running Ubuntu 22.04 under MATE.  I get the following error
Setting up python3 (3.10.6-1~22.04.1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 55, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of xfce4-panel-profiles
error running python rtupdate hook xfce4-panel-profiles
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4

This leads to a whole list of errors which all appear to stem from this error.  The funny part is the system is functioning normally with no problems in python or any of the other 43 programs for which errors were encountered while processing. However, I cannot upgrade the system to 24.04 because to these errors.  I have tried searching the internet for fixes but nothing has worked so far and several have made the system non-functional. I can provide the full listing to dkpg --configure -a if it is helpful.
Thanks for any help.

Changing the system python default will cause problems with scripts expecting the old version. For your own use, set up a container, or use miniforge3 to create an environment to run your scripts.

Did you manually change the python version? Ubuntu 22.04 already comes with python3.10. Or was it an automatic update?
